# Es posible que con algún caso de prueba, este código pueda arrojar "Segmentation Fault"?

Tags: c++

La idea es *"Desarrollar un programa que almacene los números primos que existen hasta un límite superior ingresado por el usuario.
Luego el usuario debe ingresar la posición del número primo a buscar, recuerde que los arreglos empiezan en la posición 0.
Si en caso la posición del número primo no existe, el programa debe informar del error"

**Ejemplo de input:**

100

21

**Ejemplo de output:**

El numero primo en la posicion 21 es 79

---

**Ejemplo de input:**

100

71

**Ejemplo de output:**

El numero primo en la posicion 71 no existe
*

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool esPrimo(int numero);

int main()
{
    int primos[100] = {0};
    int limite, posicion, count = 0;

    cout << ""; cin >> limite;

    for (int i = 0; i <= limite; i++)
    {
        if (esPrimo(i))
        {
            primos[count] = i;
            count++;
        }
    }

    cout << ""; cin >> posicion;

    if (posicion >= count)
        cout << "El numero primo en la posicion " << posicion << " no existe" << endl;
    else
        cout << "El numero primo en la posicion " << posicion << " es " << primos[posicion] << endl;

    return 0;
}

bool esPrimo(int numero)
{
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= numero; i++)
        if (numero % i == 0)
            k++;
        return k == 2;
}
```

Comment: Sí, te puede dar `Segmentation fault` si `count` llega a ser igual a 100

Comment: puedes comprobar que count no exceda el tamaño del array antes de asignar o, aún mejor en mi opinión, puedes usar un `vector<int>`

Comment: Puedes verificarlo en el for: `count < 100 && i <= limite`

Answer (score 1):

Aquí:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= limite; i++)
{
    if (esPrimo(i))
    {
        primos[count] = i;
        count++;
    }
}
```

Si límite suficientemente grande, accederás a memoria que no pertenece a `primos` cuando `count` supere 99. Si quieres evitarlo añade `count` a las condiciones del bucle:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= limite && count != 100; i++)
//                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~
{
    if (esPrimo(i))
    {
        primos[count] = i;
        count++;
    }
}
```

Otra manera de evitarlo sería usar un contenedor dinámico:

```
std::vector<int> primos;

cout << ""; cin >> limite;

for (int i = 0; i <= limite; i++)
{
    if (esPrimo(i))
        primos.push_back(i);
}

...
...

std::cout << "El numero primo en la posicion " << posicion;

if (posicion > primos.size())
    std::cout << " no existe" << endl;
else
    std::cout << " es " << primos[posicion] << endl;
```

Comment: Disculpa. como añadiría el contenedor dinamico al codigo original? O por que parte del codigo original reemplazaría por el contenedor dinamico? Espero tu respuesta.

Comment: Para añadir el contenedor dinámico añade su inclusión `#include <vector>`, el resto está en la respuesta.